# ActiveMQ How to lookup external context.xml from application.properties or @Annotation [Spring Boot 1.5.8]

Tags: spring-boot, activemq-classic, jndi, context.xml, application.properties

I have a **Spring Boot 1.5.8** application built with Maven. The **project works fine with embedded activeMQ** but when I try to set an external data source I cannot get JNDI properties from context.xml located in the *`server/conf/`* directory

*This is the **context.xml**:*

```
 <Context>
    <Resource name="jdbc/TEST" auth="Container" type="javax.sql.DataSource"
                 maxTotal="100" maxIdle="30" maxWaitMillis="10000"
                 username="TEST" password="TEST" driverClassName="oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver"
                 url="jdbc:oracle:thin:@127.0.0.1:1521/TEST"/>
    <Resource name="jms/ConnectionFactory" auth="Container" 
                type="org.apache.activemq.ActiveMQConnectionFactory" 
                description="JMS Connection Factory"
                factory="org.apache.activemq.jndi.JNDIReferenceFactory" 
                brokerURL="tcp://127.0.0.1:8161" 
                brokerName="LocalActiveMQBroker"/>
    <Resource name="jms/ActQueue" 
                auth="Container" 
                type="org.apache.activemq.command.ActiveMQQueue" 
                description="TESTQueue"
                factory="org.apache.activemq.jndi.JNDIReferenceFactory" 
                physicalName="TEST.QUEUE"/>
  </Context>
```

*Originally the application data source was inside **application.properties**:*

```
# Oracle settings
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:oracle:thin:@127.0.0.1:TEST
spring.datasource.username=TEST
spring.datasource.password=TEST
spring.datasource.driver-class-name=oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver    

#ActiveMQ settings
spring.activemq.broker-url=tcp://localhost:8161
spring.activemq.broker-name=LocalActiveMQBroker
spring.activemq.user=TEST
spring.activemq.password=TEST
```

My target is to get (lookup) the JNDI resource properties site in `server/conf/context.xml` through JNDI name.

*For example, it was pretty easy for the DB, just write this two line and comment the others:*

```
# Oracle settings from external context.xml (it works!)
spring.datasource.jndi-name=java:/comp/env/jdbc/ACTIgrue
spring.datasource.driver-class-name=oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver
```

As well above how can i get `spring.activemq.broker-url=???` or `spring.activemq.broker-name=???`

->Every help will be appreciated

**UPDATE:**

i tried also to bypass the application.properties file and get it directly with annotation as below:

```
@Resource(name="java:/comp/env/jms/ConnectionFactory")
private ActiveMQConnectionFactory conn;
```

but the following excepition occurred:

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No bean named 'java:/comp/env/jms/ConnectionFactory'
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Finally i have found a solution, [at this link](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/boot-features-messaging.html#boot-features-jms-jndi) .

So **this is the correct instruction** to put in the application.properties to instance an ActiveMQConnectionFactory bean from JNDI name::

```
spring.jms.jndi-name=java:/comp/env/jms/ConnectionFactory
```

I hope this helps ;)